# Python - How to get a column's mean if there is String value too

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am new to python. I have a .csv dataset. There is a column called BasePay.

Most of the values in column is type int, but some values are "Not Provided".

I am trying to get mean value of BasePay as:

```
sal['BasePay'].mean()
```

But it gives me error of :

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.

I want to omit that string columns. How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: ...is this pandas?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes i am using pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaN`s, so `mean` working nice:

```
out = pd.to_numeric(sal['BasePay'], errors='coerce').mean()
```

**Sample**:

```
sal = pd.DataFrame({'BasePay':[1, 'Not Provided', 2, 3, 'Not Provided']})
print (sal)
        BasePay
0             1
1  Not Provided
2             2
3             3
4  Not Provided

print (pd.to_numeric(sal['BasePay'], errors='coerce'))
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    NaN
Name: BasePay, dtype: float64

out = pd.to_numeric(sal['BasePay'], errors='coerce').mean()
print (out)
2.0
```

Comment: It is working thanks. Can you explain what does mean erorrs='coerce' parameter?

Comment: @FurkanKaracan - If check link, there is `errors : {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’

        If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN` - so invalid values are replaced to NaNs

Comment: @FurkanKaracan - Added sample data for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because, when you import the dataset, the empty fields will be filled with NaN(pandas),  So you have two options 1.Either you convert pandas.nan to  0 or remove the NaN's,  by drop.nan

This can also be achieved by using np.nanmean()

Comment: This is not true. `.mean()` will work fine with NaN values (ignore them by default). E.g. `pd.DataFrame([1,np.nan, 2]).mean()` will return `1.5`

Comment: How i can use mean after df['BasePay'].dropna

Comment: And my case includes some string values other np.nan . i want to omit them

Answer (score 1):

If you store data from the BasePay column in a list, you can do as follows:

```
for i in l:
if type(i) == int:
    x.append(i)

mean = sum(x) / len(x)
print(mean)
```